# Construct new column from existing columns without re specifying dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, assign

If you want to create a new column in a dataframe from other columns, you can write it pretty concise in R. In Python however I have not find a way yet to do this because I have to state the dataframe everytime I use a column if I'm not mistaken. I there a way to state once which dataframe to use, after which you only have to specify the columns? I put two examples below to illustrate my point.

In Python:

```
my_dataframe=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1.0,2.0,3.0],
                 'col2':[4.0,5.0,6.0],
                 'col3':[0.25,0.25,0.25],
                 'first_column':[0.5,0.5,0.5],
                 'second_column':[1.0,2.0,3.0],
                 'third_column':[4.0,5.0,6.0],
                 'fourth_column':[0.25,0.25,0.25]})

my_dataframe['new_column'] = my_dataframe['col1'] - (my_dataframe['third_column'] / my_dataframe['fourth_column']) * my_dataframe['second_column']
```

In R

```
my_dataframe <- data_frame(col1 = c(1,2,3),
                           col2 = c(4,5,6),
                           col3 = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25),
                           first_column = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
                           second_column = c(1, 2, 3),
                           third_column = c(4, 5, 6),
                           fourth_column = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25))

my_dataframe <- my_dataframe %>% mutate(new_column = col1 - (third_column / fourth_column) * second_column)
```

The closest I can get to is using a lambda as in the example below, which is pretty clean, however the column auto-complete function does not work. My question therefore is, is there another method I haven't thought of which is both clean and provides an auto-complete?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]})
df.assign(B=df.A, C=lambda x:x['A']+ x['B'])
```

Comment: What do you mean by auto-complete?

Comment: @SandeepKadapa This might be specific to Jupyter Notebooks, but when typing: `my_dataframe['second_co']` and pressing TAB, this autocompletes to `second_column`. My point is that when using a lambda, the column names are not  linked to the argument x such that an autocomplete feature is not working. I find this a handy feature to have when working with many columns.

Comment: please include your comment in question. In my opinion, the problem deals with more of IDE's that we use than python.

Answer (score 1):

Try df.apply

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]})

Then

df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['A'], axis=1)
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['A']+x['B'] , axis=1)
```

Output

```
   A  B  C
0  1  1  2
1  2  2  4
2  3  3  6
```